# what is wrong with this java code?

Tags: java

I was going through an ICPC question [HERE](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AMR12G/)

The problem boils down to finding maximum.'s which can be achieved with K operations in a matrix having * and . such that we are allowed to toggle elements in a row in one operation.I first toggled the rows which result in positive or zero(toggling a row 2 times gives 0 change) change in *'s in decreasing order. At the end, if there is 1 toggle left, toggle the row with the least absolute value amongst the rows having negative changes.

Here is my code - [BELOW CODE IN IDEONE.COM WITH SOME TEST CASES](http://ideone.com/etDkSF)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    for (t = t; t > 0; t--) { 
      int n = sc.nextInt();
      int m = sc.nextInt();
      int k = sc.nextInt();
      char[][] array = new char[n][m] ;
      int[] tracker = new int[n];
      int[] trackerl = new int[n];
      int i,j;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String temp = sc.next();
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {             
          array[i][j] = (temp.charAt(j));  
        }   
      }
      int light = 0, diamond = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          if (array[i][j] == '*') {
            diamond++;
          }     
        }
        tracker[i] = diamond;
        diamond = 0;
      }


      int a, b;
      int temp;
      int sortTheNumbers = n;

      for (a = 1; a < sortTheNumbers; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < sortTheNumbers-a; b++) {
          if (tracker[b] > tracker[b + 1]) {
            temp = tracker[b];
            tracker[b] = tracker[b + 1];
            tracker[b + 1] = temp;
          }
        }
      }

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        trackerl[i]=m-tracker[i];

      int br = 0;
      try {
        if (m % 2 == 0) {
          for ( i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
            if (tracker[i] > (m) / 2)
              br++;  
        }
        if (m % 2 !=0 ) {
          for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
            if (tracker[i] >= (m + 1) / 2)
              br++;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }

      int ans = 0;
      try {
        if (br >= k) {
          for (i = n - 1; i > (n - 1 - k); i--)
            ans += tracker[i];

          for (i = (n - 1 - k); i >= 0; i--)
            ans += trackerl[i];       
        }

        if (br < k) {
          if (br != 0 && br != n) {
            for (i = n - 1; i > (n - br); i--) {
              ans += tracker[i];
              k--;
            }

            int pass1 = 0, pass2 = 0;
            if (k % 2 == 0)
              pass1 = Math.max(tracker[(n - br)] + tracker[(n - br - 1)],
                                        trackerl[(n - br)] + trackerl[(n - br - 1)]);
              if (k % 2 != 0)
                pass2 = Math.max(tracker[(n - br)] + trackerl[(n - br - 1)],
                                          trackerl[(n - br)] + tracker[(n - br - 1)]);
                // System.out.print("Hp" + tracker[(n - br)]);
              }

              ans += Math.max(pass1, pass2);
              for (i = (n - 2 - br); i >= 0; i--)
                ans += trackerl[i];
              }
              if (br != 0 && br == n) {
                for (i = n - 1; i > (n - br); i--) {
                  ans += tracker[i];
                  k--;
                }
                if (k % 2 != 0) {
                  ans += tracker[(n - br)];
                }
                if (k % 2 == 0) {
                  ans += trackerl[(n - br)];
                }
                for (i = (n - 1 - br); i >= 0; i--) {
                  ans += trackerl[i];
                }        
              }
              if (br == 0) {
                if (k % 2 != 0) {
                  ans += tracker[(n - 1)];
                }
                if (k % 2 == 0) {
                  ans += trackerl[(n - 1)];
                }
                for (i = (n - 2); i >= 0; i--) {
                  ans += trackerl[i];
                }
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          System.out.println(""+ans);
        }
      }
    }
```

Whichever test case I choose gives the correct answer. I maintained variety in my test cases, as you can see from the link.Still the code isn't correct as it is not accepted by the judge. I really can't find where is the flaw.Is it in my code or my logic? Please point it out for me.

Comment: First three things that are wrong with the code: 1) It's not pleasantly indented; 2) it's a single *very* long method. 3) It catches any exception and assumes that the answer is then fit to print, ignoring the exception itself. Fixing all of those is likely to make it easier to find the actual behavioural problem.

Comment: That is allot of poorly formatted and named code which is very hard for someone else to read.  I suggest you look at other sample answers if you can get them as your are probably making an assumption which is  different to what they do.

Comment: The question seems to ask for maximum *, not maximum .

Comment: Jon and Peter> Thanks!
@Guido > Maximum . , after all possible beneficial row toggling

Comment: @user1972269 if you look the test cases at the bottom of the question you linked, the first one would return 0 not 4 if it was for .

Comment: @guido > it should be 4
2 2 1
..
**
K = 1 here,so rotate the 2nd row
Resulting configuration - 
..
..
So,the answer is 4

Comment: _"Gimli challenges Legolas to turn *on* as many diamonds as possible using EXACTLY K on/off operations of the switches." [...] The ith line denotes the state of the diamonds in the ith row, where '*' denotes a diamond which is on and '.' denotes a diamond which is off._

Answer (score 2):

Writing code is the same as writing a paper, there are grammar, spelling, punctuation, and other rules which make the code readable and the point clear.  Studying these *and* writing clear code pays off, not just for others who need to read your code, but for you too (you will see more of your own errors).

I'll just point out a few items I ran across when formatting your code. (Examples are from memory and not your code)

```
if(x=3;y>(2-2-x);y++)
```

Don't write a line like this because

1. **if** is not a function, and choosing "if(" over "if (" makes it look a little more like a function.  The same goes with the keyword **while**.
2. Putting multiple strings of arithmetic operations (especially '+' and '-') in a long line (as in "(2-2-x)" confuses the dual roles that the '-' character can play, you would be better off putting in spaces "(2 - 2 - x)" to make the reader realize that we are dealing with multiple subtractions, without a unary negation operation (negative number).
3. **if** statements require three parameters (separated by semicolons).  putting in spaces after each parameter can signal the reader that they are in the "next" parameter.  Favour "if (x=3; y>(2-2-x); y++)" over "if (x=3;y>(2-2-x);y++)".

In the continued example

```
if(x=3;y>(2-2-x);y++) 
  {x=3;y=2;}
```

The brackets on the following line create reading comprehension issues.

1. They are subject to the same formatting problems as having no brackets after an if statement.  By putting your entire block on a line, you confuse blocks and lines, and any line reordering will dramatically affect the operation of your program.  This is bad.  To fix this, favour "if (x = 3; y >(2 - 2 - x); y++) {".
2. There is a compound statement on a single line which mimics the formatting of the if statement above it, which could confuse a reader into believing that this is part of a subsequent nested if statement.  It is far more readable to put the two assignment statements on their own lines.
3. You tie the end of the block to a statement, which couples the block boundaries to a particular operation.  Often one needs to update their code, and odds are slim that the statement and end of the block should be connected over the lifetime of the program.  Favour putting the end of block delimiter on a non statement line.

All of the above points, when used together, result in code that looks like

```
if (x = 3; y > (2 - 2 - x); y++) {
  x = 2;
  y = 3;
}
```

After some simple formatting, it is clear that you have multiple blocks of "if this, then that".  It is also clear that lots of these blocks follow a pattern, "If this, then that.  If not this, then that".  The language has a built-in ability to handle such a pattern with an "else" block attached to the prior if block.

(example directly from your code)

```
        if (k % 2 != 0) {
          ans += tracker[(n - 1)]
        }
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
          ans += trackerl[(n - 1)];
        }
```

which could much more cleanly be written

```
        if (k % 2 != 0) {
          ans += tracker[(n - 1)]
        } else {
          ans += trackerl[(n - 1)];
        }
```

or, using reordering to emphasize the equality over the inequality

```
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
          ans += tracker1[(n - 1)]
        } else {
          ans += tracker[(n - 1)];
        }
```

One could go on, but after you make changes like these, really your code is starting in a much better place, so it doesn't make sense to talk about higher level techniques of making your code readable until some of the basics are done.  Even so, I will recommend that you use full words for your variable names that attempt to describe the variable's purpose.

Good luck, and in my reformatting, I might have clipped a closing block delimiter (they don't match up) or maybe it wasn't there in the first place (not like one could check in the unformatted version).

Comment: Thanks for formatting my code ! I really appreciate that . But what I wanted to know was - why am I not getting the correct answer ? Is there a flaw in my logic ?